# Limits of trivial expressions involving the logarithmic function

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

By simplifying the trivial expression inside the limit, $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\frac{x}{x-1}}{\frac{x}{x-1}}=1$$ My question is: can we do the same (I suspect we can't) if $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\log\frac{x}{x-1}}{\log\frac{x}{x-1}}?$$

Comment: If you have $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{f(x)}$ where $f(a)=0$, the numerator behaves the same close to the zero point as the denominator(since they are the same function) and so the ratio is essentially 1 for $x\neq a$ and $\lim_{x\to a}$ is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression inside the logarithm is identically $1$ when $x \ne 1$, and those are the only values of $x$ that matter when calculating the limit at $1$. So the answer is the limit of $\log (1)$, which is  of course $0$.

The second expression is similar. When $x \ne 1$ the expression inside the limit is  just $1/1$ so the limit is $1$.

Neither question really has much to do with logarithms, except that in the second question the logarithms are undefined when $x$ is between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: So, in the second expression, if $x\in[0,1]$, does $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\log\frac{x}{x-1}}{\log\frac{x}{x-1}}$ still equal 1?

Comment: The second expression is makes no sense when, say, $x = 1/2$ since $(1/2)/(1-(1/2)) = -1$ and there is no such thing as $\log(-1)$. You can evaluate the limit as $x \to 1^+$. That's the limit of $1$, which is $1$.